# Call to undefined function post() in php controller with 2 forms - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I am new to CodeIgniter. I have a view with 2 forms. 
Below is the code for view with two forms

```
 <?php echo form_open("Main/login");?>

    <br /><br />
    <table>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><input name="txtLoginEmail" style="width:265px; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
   <input name="txtLoginPassword" style="width:265px; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control"/>
    </td>
    </tr><td>
    <input id="btnSignIn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Sign In"/>
    <br /><br />
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table> 
    <?php echo form_close(); ?>

    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="div_signup">
    <?php echo form_open("Main/register");?>

        <!-- Registration Panel -->
    <br /> <br />

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
<input name="txtRegisterFirstName" style="width:265px; margin-right: 5px; margin-left: 5px" type="text" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"/>                
            </td>
        </tr>       
        <tr>
            <td valign="top"><br />       
                <input name="btnRegister" style="margin-right: 5px;" value="Register" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
                <br /><br />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

This is my controller code with two functions to handle two forms.
It simply receives post request and try to get parameters

```
public function login(){

   $userEmail=$this->input->post('txtLoginEmail');
   $password= $this->input->post('txtLoginPassword');
    $data['username']=$userEmail;

    $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
}

public function register()
{

    $fname= $this->input->post('txtRegisterFirstName');
    $lname=$this->input>post('txtRegisterLastName');
    $data['fname']=$fname;
    $data['lname']=$lname;

    $this->load->model('Main_Model');
    $this->Main_Model->register($data);
}
```

While running project, When I submit first form(Main/Login) it works fine.

But while submitting second form(Main/Register), it throws error

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function post() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Voyager\application\controllers\Main.php**

Is there any other way I should handle multiple forms in a page.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load form helper class in constructor method.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```

**Note:-** Please change `$lname=$this->input>post('txtRegisterLastName');` to `$lname=$this->input->post('txtRegisterLastName');`

Comment: No when I run project I get this error: Call to a member function helper() on null

Comment: Please check `$this->load->helper('form');`

Comment: Oh. It was silly one. Your Note made it work. Thanks a lot. :)